# How to resolve 'undefined reference to' error for C++ project in Qt Creator using CMakeLists?

Tags: c++, reference, qt-creator, cmakelists-options

Title: Compilation error with undefined reference to 'rotation90' function in C++ project

Problem description:
I am working on a C++ project using Qt Creator. In my project, I have the following files: primitives.cpp, primitives.h, and main.cpp. During compilation, I encounter the following error:

error: CMakeFiles/myProject.dir/main.cpp.obj:C:/Users/myProject/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `rotation90(std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator > > > const&)'

The error message explicitly mentions the undefined reference to the 'rotation90' function, but I am confused about the cause of the error. I have declared the 'rotation90' function in primitives.h and defined it in primitives.cpp. I have included primitives.h in both primitives.cpp and main.cpp.

// main.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "primitives.h"

int main(){
    const std::vector<std::vector<int>> grille = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> resultat = rotation90(grille);

    for (const auto& ligne : resultat){
        for(const auto& element : ligne){
            std::cout << element << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

// primitives.cpp

```
#include "primitives.h"
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

std::vector<std::vector<int>> rotation90(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& grille){
    int n = grille.size();
    int m = (n > 0) ? grille[0].size() : 0;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> resultat(m, std::vector<int>(n, 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            resultat[j][n - i - 1] = grille[i][j];
        }
    }

    return resultat;
}
```

// primitives.h

```
#ifndef PRIMITIVES_H
#define PRIMITIVES_H

#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<int>> rotation90(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& grille);

#endif // PRIMITIVES_H
```

## CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(myProject LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core LinguistTools)

set(TS_FILES myProject_fr_FR.ts)

set(SOURCES
  main.cpp
  primitives.cpp
  primitives.h
  ${TS_FILES}
)

add_executable(myProject ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(myProject PRIVATE Qt5::Core)
```

Additionally, I have updated the CMakeLists.txt file by replacing the previous 'add_library' command with the following code:

```
set(SOURCES
  myproject.cpp
  myproject.h
  primitives.cpp
  primitives.h
  main.cpp
  ${TS_FILES}
)

add_executable(myProject ${SOURCES})
```

However, I still encounter the same compilation error.

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this issue.

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code you are compiling? It should fail earlier, at compilation phase, when you try to bind non-const reference to `const` vector in `rotation90(grille)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Yksisarvinen for your answer, it was indeed the exact code I was compiling. As you pointed out, the issue was with the missing 'const' keyword. I added 'const' in the definition of the rotation90 function, and now it works perfectly!

Below is the modification in my primitives.cpp file:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> rotation90(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& grid)
```